# call a path from .properties in xml

Tags: java, xml

I have an xml which calls a path and the location is hard coded.

```
<path=c:/... />
```

Does anyone know how to use .properties to put in the path and then call it from there?
Im doing this for security reasons.

EDIT

Following the tutorial
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Basic+Studio+Tutorial

the path of the inbound is called as follows:

```
<file:inbound-endpoint  path="C: ../>
```

Can it be loaded from a property file?

Comment: Can you be more clear.

Comment: pease add some sample code, so we can better understood what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code to load a propertie file is:

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\prop.properties"));
    String path = prop.getProperty("pathname");
```

but then you have the hardcode path to the propertie file:
you could just pass the path as an arg for the main methode:

```
public static void main(String Args[]){ 
    try {
        if(Args != null){
            if(Args[1] != null){//Load XML or prop File                 try{
                    properties.load(new FileInputStream(Args[1]));
                }catch(Exception e){
                    throw new Exception("Error loading PropertieFile: "+Args[1] + " :"+e.getMessage());
                }
            }else{
                throw new Exception("No File Found!");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
  <comment>Application Configuration</comment>
  <entry key="data.folder">D:\App\Data</entry>
  <entry key="jdbc.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb</entry>
</properties>
```

LoadXmlProperties .java

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class LoadXmlProperties {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LoadXmlProperties lxp = new LoadXmlProperties();
        try {
            Properties properties = lxp.readProperties();
            /*
             * Display all properties information
             */
            properties.list(System.out);

            /*
             * Read the value of data.folder and jdbc.url configuration
             */
            String dataFolder = properties.getProperty("data.folder");
            System.out.println("dataFolder = " + dataFolder);
            String jdbcUrl = properties.getProperty("jdbc.url");
            System.out.println("jdbcUrl = " + jdbcUrl);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Properties readProperties() throws Exception {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("configuration.xml");
        properties.loadFromXML(fis);

        return properties;
    }
}
```